# Images replacement

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, bufferedimage

How would i go about replacing the image called hangmanImg every time it go's through the loop?

```
public void postImg() {
  String imgName = Integer.toString(numError);
  String hangmanImg = imgName.concat(".jpg");
  try{
    BufferedImage myImg = ImageIO.read(new File(hangmanImg));
    JLabel hangman = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myImg));
    hangman.setSize(600,600);
    hangman.setLocation(300, 50);
    add(hangman);
    repaint();
  }catch(IOException ex){
    System.out.println("BEGIN CATCH: " + ex.getMessage());
    JLabel error = new JLabel(hangmanImg);
    add(error);
    error.setSize(200,100);
    error.setLocation(300, 20);
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect I've said this to you before, but..  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Also, please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: as for naming conventions I fixed the naming convention yesterday. But i think I picked up my old code when i was trying to trouble shoot last night. Sorry will fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hangman.setIcon(new ImageIcon...)`, see always the javadoc [JLabel.setIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29)